# Adding Zend Framework to php.ini include_path causes Drupal site to go blank

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, drupal

My hosting plan allows me to host multiple sites.  When I try to add the Zend Framework libraries to php.ini, another Drupal site I have becomes a completely blank whitescreen.  This is the offending line:

include_path = "/home/myusername/myzendusingsite.com/html/Zend"

The Drupal site is located at:

/home/myusername/mydrupalsite.com/html

There should not be any conflict between Drupal and Zend.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any assistance,

Orville

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add "." as well. Example:

```
include_path = ".:/home/myusername/myzendusingsite.com/html/Zend"
```